# Duplicating commerce kickstart's product types view modes

Tags: 7, commerce

I can see that Commerce Kickstart distribution has several more view modes for product types like: **product in cart** or **node:product list**, which are not listed, by default, after commerce module installation on plain Drupal.

How can I get those with only commerce module installed?

Is it some additional code or I am just missing some settings?

I found a module, [Entity view modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode), which seems to be good for the job but Commerce Kickstart does not have this module installed.

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1):

In Commerce Kickstart, **Commerce Kickstart Product** (`commerce_kickstart_product`) and **Commerce Kickstart Product UI** (`commerce_kickstart_product_ui`) modules provide the extra view modes. And are not available as a separate module.

So, you can use **Entity view modes** (`entity_view_mode`) to create your custom view mode.